# Generate variable HTML table for DataTables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

**Background**

I am trying to generate a variable HTML table for use with DataTables.

I've built a web viewer with a couple of selectboxes which are dependable on each other. When you select an option in "Select tabel", "Select column" changes. When you alter "Select column", "Select attribute" changes. Etc.

The results from "Select attribute" are placed in an array, which I want to use to generate the tableheaders that DataTables need.

Example:

Say `myArray` looks something like  `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]`, the generated report should look something like the code below.

**Question**

Because `myArray` has no fixed size and content, I can't just make a static HTML table in my index file.

<s>How do I make a function that loops through `myArray` and generates a report based on the data in `myArray`?</s>

**Edit:**

I've got my code working in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0mfc3nu/4/) now, however when I try to incorporate it in my web viewer code, I get an error: [image]
The report is messed up and looks like this:

[image]

What causes this and how do I get my code to work outside of JSfiddle?

**Code**

```
<div id="report_comes_here">
  <table id="report">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>bbb</th>
            <th>ccc</th>
            <th>ddd</th>       
            <th>eee</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use table headers ?

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy(). This will allow you to update a table that has already been made into a datatable. @Ramkee's answer is grand but won't allow you to edit it easily after the table has been initialised once - not with different columns anyway.

Comment: I already use something like that to destroy and rebuild my current (static) report. Now I just need to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"] ;
var count = array.length;

var TABLE = ' <table id="report" class= "table table-striped table-bordered">';
    TABLE += '<thead ><tr><th>Sample Head</th></tr></thead>'
    TABLE += '<tbody>';
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        TABLE += "<tr>";
        TABLE += "<td>" + array[i] + "</td>"
        TABLE += "</tr>";
    }
    TABLE += "</tbody></table>";
```

Now you can append `TABLE` variable to your required `DIV ID` using Jquery

```
$("#report_comes_here").html(TABLE);
$('#report').DataTable();
```

You can find Demo at [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0mfc3nu/3/)

If you find any difficulties please let me know.

Comment: I should have been a bit more clear. I wanted table headers, not table rows/data. I've edited your code a bit to generate what I meant. However, I can't get the code to work outside of JSfiddle, see my edited question.